# Specifying a parameter when calling PropertyValueFactory

Tags: uitableview, javafx, tableview, tablecolumn

I'm currently creating a TableView in JavaFX and I wondering if when I am creating a TableColumn if I can pass in a parameter, here is my code snippet:

```
// Create column
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy");
TableColumn<WeeklyReport,String> tc = new TableColumn<WeeklyReport,String>(sdf.format(d));
tc.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("WC"));
```

This calls the getWC() of every WeeklyReport object in the tableview, however I need a way of passing this a date to pull over a specified date.

If not, are there any workarounds or other easy ways to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this with `PropertyValueFactory`. Just implement the callback directly:

```
tc.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().getWC(...)));
```